# MILP formulation of constraint

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I'm very new to MILP, and I'm testing python-mip.
I'm trying to model a simple power distribution system with some constraints, but I'm stuck....

I want to find a valid power balance between a device, a power loss and a power input, that maximisizes, if possible, power_provided_to_device, like:

max(power_provided_to_device)

power_available = power_provided_to_device + unused_power

with:
0. 0 < lb <= power_provided_to_device <= ub

1. if power_available < lb: power_provided_to_device = 0, unused_power = power_available
2. if lb <= power_available <= ub: power_provided_to_device = power_available, unused_power = 0
3. if ub < power_available: power_provided_to_device = ub, unused_power = power_available - ub

I made it work for power_available >= lb.
However, I just can't figure out how to fulfill the condition 1. . I tried some exemples with the bigM and binary variables, piecewise functions, but with no success...

Sorry for my poor formating and problem description.
Thanks a lot for your kind help!
Max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective and linear constraints naturally satisfy conditions 2 and 3.  For condition 1, you want to enforce
$$\text{power_available} < \text{lb} \implies \text{power_provided_to_device} = 0$$
Introduce a binary variable $x$ and big-M constraints
\begin{align}
\text{lb} - \text{power_available} &\le M_1 x \tag1\\
\text{power_provided_to_device} &\le M_2 (1-x) \tag2\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces
$$\text{power_available} < \text{lb} \implies x=1$$
Constraint $(2)$ enforces
$$x=1 \implies \text{power_provided_to_device} = 0$$
You can take $M_1=\text{lb}$ and $M_2=\text{ub}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I'll give it a try!
In the meantime, I've found a way to solve that with a special ordered set (2).

The function returns 0 within [0,lb[, device_output_power(power_provided_to_device) otherwise.
Pretty useful I admit.
Thanks again.